# Django - listening to rabbitmq, in a synchronized way. without celery. in the same process of the web bound django

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq

I need to implement a quite simple Django server that server some http requests and listens to a rabbitmq message queue that streams information into the Django app (that should be written to the db). the data must be written to the db in a synchronized order , So I can't use the obvious celery/rabbit configuration.  I was told that there is no way to do this in the same Django project. since Django would listen to http requests on It's process. and It can't handle another process to listen for Rabbit - forcing me to to add Another python/django project for the rabbit/db writes part - working with the same models The http bound django project works with.. You can smell the trouble with this config from here. .. Any Ideas how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain the scenario in more detail? It sounds as if you need to create a separate component for this, ideally, based on a real-time framework such as Tornado.

Comment: Exactly what I'm afraid of.. Our server side is already spread with java, node and django. I don't want to introduce tornado to this mess.. The scenario is:
1. subscribing to a message bus - a rabbitmq channel
2. writing the data to the db, when ever I get new data
3. serving the data to clients based on http requests (Plain Old Django)

Comment: Can you use celery tasks on the producer side of the message queue? If so you can continue to have Django deal with the calls, just have celery worker processes listening on the queue and executing the tasks as they come in. If you are dealing with arbitrary data on the queue, you'll need a different dedicated component.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else bumps into this problem:

The solution is using a RabbitMQ consumer from a different process (But in the same Django codebase) then Django (Not the running through wsgi, etc. you have to start it by it self)
The consumer, connects to the appropriate rabbitmq queues and writes the data into the Django models. Then the usual Django process(es) is actually a "read model" of the data inserted/updated/created/deleted as delivered by the message queue (RabbitMQ or other) from a remote process.

Comment: I just bumped into it, a few years later. But yes, my solution was the same as yours, spawning a new process from Django to run the consumer.

I also tried the 2 Django instances approach, with both instances identically built from Docker to maintain consistency. It worked fine, but feels inelegant.